# Mapbox Studio tileset is missing the bottom corner of polygon after upload to studio

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I am uploading a shapefile to Mapbox Studio. Here is a screenshot of the shapefile polygon in QGis

This is the polygon in QGis

[image]

Now, when I zip the files and upload them as a new tileset, the bottom corner is missing at the edge of a Tile boundary. See the screenshot below.

See the screenshot below to see the problem.

[image]

How can I prevent this problem when I upload to Mapbox Studio? I have had this problem with every shapefile that I upload.